# How to select 100 unique values?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How to select 100 unique codenumber from a table such that every observation of the unique codenumber will be pulled?

```
select top 100* from srv.table01 #THIS WONT WORK
```

table01 contains columns of codenumber, date, transtype

sample would be below: I want to get 100 unique code numbers from my table such that all observation of those 100 unique code will be included

```
codenumber    date    transtype
132        09/09/09    Cash
132        09/05/09    Cash
132        09/22/09    Card
132          .
222          .
132        09/23/10    Card
123
311
523
334
132
```

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 0):

```
select *from (select *from table group by codenumber) where ROWNUM<101;
```

It should work now!

Comment: that wont assure me that I got all unique top 100 code numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

12c:

```
    select codenumber
      from srv.table01
  group by codenumber
fetch next 100 rows only
```

11r2 and earlier:

```
select *
  from (  select codenumber
            from srv.table01
        group by codenumber)
 where rownumber <= 100
```

Comment: What's the difference between FETCH FIRST and FETCH NEXT, in this case?

Comment: Don't you need an ORDER BY the the second query's sub-query?

Comment: Jarlh, none really,. they are both valid for grammatical purposes. like use next for :"*SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY I OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY*" here, next is grammatically correct. (I should have used first in my example).  Same as "create procedure ABC *AS* " and in a package  "Procedure ABC *is*" you can choose to use "is" or "as".

As for the order by, the question didn't really mention any order.

Answer (score 0):

You're after all rows for 100 codenumbers? If so, then I think what you're after is something like:

```
select codenumber, date, transtype
from   (select codenumber,
               date,
               transtype,
               dense_rank() over (order by codenumber) dr
        from   srv.table01)
where  dr <= 100;
```

This works on Oracle, and I believe it should work on SQL Server too. It also has the advantage of only accessing the table once, but whether doing the sort to get the dense_rank is more costly than doing a second pass through the table is something you'd need to test against your data.

Answer (score -2):

I got it this way! I have my 100 unique code numbers and I got all its record from the table. Thanks for the help though :)

```
select *
from
(select TOP 100*
from(select distinct codenumber
from srv.table01)x) as a
left Join srv.table01 as b
on a.codenumber=b.codenumber
```

Comment: There is no way this solution will work with Oracle.

Comment: I don't think Oracle has TOP keyword

Comment: Sql? I'm using toad.

Comment: Oracle don't support `TOP` clause. May be you are using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @Surename I guess so. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why a left join? You're selecting the 100 code numbers from the same table you're left joining to, so they will always appear. You could change that to an inner join without issue.